# Carbon properties

Tags: physical-chemistry, phase

Can carbon in the form of graphite melt or even boil? Under what experimental conditions? I ask this question because I found in a very serious book (Tables CRM Commission romande de chimie) information that I do not understand:

- sublimation at 3650 ° C
- boiling at 4827 ° C

But if the carbon sublimates at 3650 ° C, how does it boil? Is the work already done?
How valid are these values. thank you in advance

Comment: That book more *pretends* to be serious. You are right, carbon cannot boil at 4827°C if it already sublimes at 3650. The fact is that carbon has it's triple point somewhere around 11 MPa and 4600°C. (wikipedia gives +-300 on that temperature. It's extremely  difficult to maintain such a pressure and temperature at the same time, let alone measure anything.)

Comment: Don't forget, different behaviours are possible under different conditions (eg pressure). What conditions did the source specify?

Comment: Mithoron's reference displays a diagram showing that no liquid carbon can exist at less than 100 atm, whatever the temperature. Carbon sublimes at ordinary pressures.